# Yii2 - How to get the sum of computational figures

Tags: php, mysql, view, yii2

I am working on an invoice in yii2 whereby the item `price` and `qnty` are stored but the `amount` of each item is computed by the product of `qnty` and `price`. 
I now want to get the `totals` of the invoice below the invoice whereby this figure will be the sum of all the `amounts` of the items of the invoice. Bearing in mind that the `amount` value is computed and not stored, how can I compute the `totals` from these figures?
Take note that I cannot get the values directly from the database table as the `price` value is a derivative of other functions.

Here is my view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\RepeatInvoice */

$this->title = 'Invoice';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Repeat Invoices', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="repeat-invoice-view">

    <h1 align="center"><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p align="right">
        <?= Html::a('Print', ['update', '#' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Export to PDF', ['#', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Email Invoice', ['#', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </p>

    <!-- invoice -->
    <section class="invoice">
      <!-- title row -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="page-header">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <?php echo $model->company->name; ?>
            <small class="pull-right">Date Created: <?php echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime($model->created_at)) ?></small>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- info row -->
        <div class="well row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Repeat the invoice every
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo $model->repeat_every.' '.$model->repeat_period; ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Start Date
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime($model->start_date)) ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Due Date
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo $model->dueDate;  ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    End Date
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime($model->end_date)) ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="well row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Tenant
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo $model->lease->tenant->tenantName; ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>
                    Tenancy
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo $model->lease->leaseDetails; ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Payable to:
                </p>
                <p><strong>
                    <?php echo $model->due_after_every.' '.$model->due_after_period; ?>
                </strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>

      <!-- Table row -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($repeatInvoiceItems as $indexItem => $repeatInvoiceItem): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->item->item; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->desc; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->qnty; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->itemPrice; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->qnty * $repeatInvoiceItem->itemPrice; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

      <div class="row">
        <!-- accepted payments column -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <p class="lead">Payment Instructions:</p>

          <p class="text-muted well well-sm no-shadow" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <?php echo $model->payment_instructions; ?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">

          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <th style="width:50%">Subtotal:</th>
                <td>$250.30</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Tax (9.3%)</th>
                <td>$10.34</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Total:</th>
                <td>$265.24</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

      <!-- this row will not appear when printing -->
      <div class="row no-print">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Back</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Edit Invoice
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">
            <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Add Note
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.invoice -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create variable

1. `$lineItemPrice` : to store the line items price
2. `$subTotal`: to store all the line/row i.e. `$lineItemPrice` items price.

Add all `$lineItemPrice` in `$subTotal` inside foreach loop. And, display at the end where you wanted to display. To display `Total`, you need to calculate the `$subTotal` with `tax` and display in `Total` column.

**Code**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php 
        $subTotal = 0;
        foreach ($repeatInvoiceItems as $indexItem => $repeatInvoiceItem): ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->item->item; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->desc; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->qnty; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $repeatInvoiceItem->itemPrice; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php 
              $lineItemPrice = $repeatInvoiceItem->qnty * $repeatInvoiceItem->itemPrice;
              echo $lineItemPrice;
              $subTotal += $lineItemPrice;
              ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p class="lead">Payment Instructions:</p>
    <p class="text-muted well well-sm no-shadow" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <?php echo $model->payment_instructions; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:50%">Subtotal:</th>
          <td>$<?php echo number_format($subTotal,2);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Tax (9.3%)</th>
          <td>$10.34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Total:</th>
          <td>$265.24</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For Total,

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">Subtotal:</th>
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($subTotal,2);?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      $tax = 9.3;
      ?>
      <tr>
        <th>Tax (9.3%)</th>
        <td>
          <?php
          echo $taxAmount = ($tax * $subTotal)/100;
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total:</th>
        <td>
          <?php echo $grandTotal = $subTotal + $taxAmount;?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and clear, I never thought in that line. Thank you so much. I will accept the answer.

Comment: Yes. It was easy though. No problem. We learn from mistakes. Keep coding. Enjoy. @japheth